Heated Flooring Wiring Advice
We’re in the middle of a bathroom reno and planning to install heated floors using the Schlutter Ditra System. I’m curious if it’s possible (or even advisable) to pull power from our existing floor heating circuit in the kitchen to supply the bathroom system.
The kitchen thermostat is about 20 feet away from the bathroom, so I was thinking we might be able to wire it to that instead of running a brand new wire to the panel box (which is located in a finished basement).
I’ll definitely be hiring an electrician to handle this, but I’d love to get some advice here to see if this idea is feasible—or if I’m way off base. Plus, it’s a long weekend, so any insight now would be much appreciated!

First obvious question: can the supply cope with both on at the same time?

yes it is possible.  you just need to know the loads of the heating circuits and make sure the breaker can handle them.  it is typically to have more than one in floor heating cable on a heating circuit.
